# Prevent Chrome DevTools from Disabling Cache

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am performing local testing on Chrome by modifying some js file and saving them as local overrides.
Every time when I reload the page I see that the devtools automatically checks the *Disable Cache* option and force download all the assets like images etc. It happens every time when I reload the page even I manually deselect the option.This is not something I want and it simply slows down load of webpage. How I can I **keep cache enabled** all the time?
[image]

Comment: Disable this option in devtools preferences.

Comment: That's what I do every time but as soon as the page load starts it gets enabled automatically.

Comment: I tried on preference pane as well but still the same issue. I guess the setting is same in both the cases.

Comment: It's a bug in devtools then. Try resetting the preferences by clicking "Restore defaults and reload" button.

Comment: Performed restore to defaults but still same issue. I will file a bug with chrome devtools.